# remove a particular custom post type slug from the url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to remove a particular custom post type slug from the url in wordpress 4.7

here is that link 
      http://dmstage.com/gardencity/projects/bridge-construction/

But i need it should come like this
     http://dmstage.com/gardencity/bridge-construction/

the `projects` should be removed from the link..I just tried to rewrite it in the functions.php..But couldnot get the correct way to do it..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Try creating this function :

```
function na_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

if ( 'events' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
    return $post_link;
}

$post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'na_remove_slug', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: this one just removed the link on url..but i still appears as old one in the permalink...then wt to do?